# Virtual Keyboard in Handsontable

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, handsontable

I have a requirement to use number and character keyboard for different cell in a single application. I am using jquery keyboard js for achieving this. I am capable of passing the layout (**numc, qwertyc**) but unable to change the layout. Entire application is based on html and js.

```
afterSelectionEnd: function(instance, col, row, td) {
    //alert(col)
    var n='numc'; //qwerty
    //if(col==0 || col==4){
    if(col==1){
        n='qwertyc';
    }
    this.getActiveEditor().beginEditing();
    keyboardNum(n);       
}, 

function keyboardNum(layouts) { 
    var kb,
    $input = $(':focus');
    if ($input.length) {
        lastInput = $input;
        // close the last keyboard
        kb = lastInput.getkeyboard();

        if (kb) {
            kb.close(true);
        }
        //alert(kb);
        if (!$input.hasClass('.ui-keyboard-input')) {
            $input.keyboard({
                usePreview: false,
                initialFocus: false,
                layout: layouts
            });
        }
        $input.getkeyboard().reveal();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Also, please clarify which keyboard script you are using. http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/ ? or https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Virtual-Keyboard-Plugin-Keyboard.html ?